# Incorrect hyperlink

Tags: meteor, telescope

The hyperlink on each post is incorrect and is in the format as shown below. Is this a configuration issue or some issue with the telesope framework ?

```
http://out/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DMo2fwWoMZOo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the `site URL` setting in the Settings panel?

Comment: Yes I did, I had set it to "/", i removed that now and its working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything special that must be done on a nitrous box to get URL forwarding to work properly? I have tried the nitrous URL, a "/" and leaving it blank. None of those settings seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a trailing "/" to the Site URL setting.